# Visual Studio 2010 and IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

Is IIS included in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition, or do I have to download it separately? Furthermore, is IIS necessary so I can run a local server to test a website in asp.net?

Comment: You'll want to check out [IIS Express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509) includes the option to use [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038) from inside VS2010